# Sinon - How to check that array keys all have particular value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, unit-testing, sinon

I should preface everything by saying that I have *never* written a unit test before, so if you can be explicit for me and not presume knowledge of advanced practices. Than you.

I'm trying to create a unit test that checks to make sure that every key `"x"` has the value of `"y"`. My javascript passes either `"a"`, `"b"`, or `"c"` into `module.exports.handler = async (letter) =>`.

This filters a **JSON** based on the argument `"a"`, `"b"`, or `"c"` and returns an array of objects with key/value pairs.

If `"a"` is passed in, then an array of objects with key `"x"` all have value `"y"`;

if `"b"` is passed as the argument, then an array of objects with key `"x"` have value `"z"`;

and finally if argument `"c"` is passed in, then an array of objects with key `"x"` have value `"w"`.

```
 describe('filtering spec', () => {
   it('should return an array of objects each of which with y as the value', async () => {
     // Makes sure the returned array of objects all have y as the corresponding value for key x
   });

   it('should return an array of objects each of which with z as the value', async () => {
     // Makes sure the returned array of objects all have z as the corresponding value for the key x
   });

   it('should return an array of objects each of which with y as the value', async () => {
     // Makes sure the returned array of objects all have w as the corresponding value for the key x
   });
```

I'm guessing I'll end up using a `matcher` in some way (see https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/matchers/)

Comment: can you post the method that you're testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use the [Array.Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method to see if any object has an unwanted value, **if there is any**, then your test should fail.

```
let array = [{x: "y"}, {x: "y"}, {x: "y"}, {x: "b"}]

isCorrect = (array, req) => {
  return (array.filter(v => v.x !== req))
}

console.log(isCorrect(array, "y").length ? "failed" : "passed")
```

As said in the comments, [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) is actually atleast **18% faster!**

```
let isSome = (list, req) => {
    return (list.some(v => v.x === req))
}
```

You could also use, [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) ...

Comment: `Array.some` would have been faster.